# Setting up Lubuntu to access /usr/src/linux-headers-3.1.x.xx?

Tags: drivers, kernel, lubuntu, c

I need to access a block of memory assigned by a FPGA to a PLX chip. Now I don't think that will be too much of a problem except when I try and use the `/include/linux-headers` they seem to be somewhat lacking in capability a.k.a USERSPACE header files. Typically they will have less functions, for instance `/include/linux/pci.h` will be only 100 lines or so.

What packages do I have to install to be able to say in my header file `#include<pci.h>` so that it actually points to the `pci.h` in `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.1.x.xx` and not the one in `/usr/include/linux`?

I know that there`s all kinds of packages but frankly all the reading just made me confused and somewhat cautious as to which one to install.

Some of the ones I've been looking at will be something like.

```
kernel-devel 
kernel-headers
dkms
```

Why would I want to install anything else and will thsese actually work for me?

Answer (score 0):

If you're programming a driver, you need the header files of the kernel you're programming for. To find out what kernel you're running, you can use `uname -a`. Install its header files with `apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`.

#### Include Syntax

Both *user* and *system* header files are included using the preprocessing directive #include. It has following two forms:

```
#include <file>
```

This form is used for *system* header files. It searches for a file named file in a standard list of system directories. You can prepend directories to this list with the -I option while compiling your source code.

```
#include "file"
```

This form is used for header files of your own program. It searches for a file named file in the directory containing the current file. You can prepend directories to this list with the -I option while compiling your source code.

[Source](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_header_files.htm)

Comment: Yea but how will I get the "environment variables(If I can call it that in Linux)" to NOT point to the "/usr/include/linux/" headers but instead point to the "/usr/src/linux-headers-3.1.x.xx" headers?

Comment: Why, using standard C includes See edit.